# How to use the token given from google reader api to view unread list in objective c

Tags: objective-c, google-reader

I am making a Google Reader App and so far I have been able to receive the sid, auth, and use those to get a token from http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token?client=clientName.

My next step if I am correct is to send a GET request using this token to a url that will return me a list of unread messages.

Problem is I do not know what url to use or how to send this GET request using the ID's i have.

Can someone please show me some code that actually does this correctly in objective c.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a NSURLRequest in Objective-C you can set a custom header like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                autorelease];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=@%", token] 
         forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

This is assuming you have two strings defined already, the URL and the token.

The URL you want is http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/read

I've written a [PHP library](https://github.com/parrots/Google-Reader-Library-for-Code-Igniter/) to interact with Google Reader's API feel free to dig around there. Specifically [line 523](https://github.com/parrots/Google-Reader-Library-for-Code-Igniter/blob/master/Reader.php#L523) is relevent to this question. The library is up to date with their latest authorization changes.

Comment: I am getting what looks to be another token. when I send that request I get //P76l5yxhBL4iTFTWpcbHHA. I am using my own google reader account info to login and I dont have any unread messages. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]autorelease];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=@%", token] 
               forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

responseStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:recieveData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"message %@", responseStr);